# Places API Radar search broken

Tags: python, json, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a simple piece of Python code to run a Radar Search with Places API and return the results coordinates in a list. I run into three problems, first, the results pulled this way do not match with doing a search on Google Maps itself using the same coordinates and parameters. Specifically, I get MANY more results on Radar Search. In a radius of 1km, I get more than 200 results for a restaurant chain name.

Second, the results go beyond 1km, my specified radius. The furthest is 1.3km away using Haversine.

Third, the results are wrong. The keyword field has no effect on the results. For example, searching for "McDonalds" or "Car" with the same parameters yield the exact same results. One of the results points to an Adidas store when I use the Place ID to find the Google description.

This is code independent, these problems are there if I just C&P this into the url bar:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=39.876186,116.439424&radius=1000&keyword=McDonalds&key=KEY

I have seen another similar post on Places API malfunctioning recently. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a support ticket open with Google about this, as we're Enterprise customers, and they have confirmed there is an issue and they're working on it. From my conversations with them over the last few days:

> There have been a few other reports of this issue and we've reported
>   the problem to the Places API team. I'll get back to you as soon as we
>   have more information from them.
>
> We've received some other reports of this and the API engineers are
>   looking at the issue with the highest priority. There's no obvious
>   cause yet, but we'll let you know when they're done investigating and
>   have determined a fix.
>
> I'm sorry to hear about the complaints that you're receiving, but
>   unfortunately the engineers haven't been able to give me an ETA yet. I
>   expect to hear back from them soon but can't give an estimate yet.

I'll post updates here as I get them.

**UPDATE** 9/8: Google's support is saying this issue will be fixed by end of the week.

**UPDATE** 9/12: Google fixed it. It was being tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7082

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will check back here at the end of the week. I tried to upvote you answer but my reputation is too low, lol.

Comment: Google has fixed this issue.